# How to set max height to a CSS grid

Tags: html, css, sass

I have the following CSS grid:

```
.grid-3x4 {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-areas:
      'a b c '
      'd e f'
      'g h i'
      'l m n';
    }
```

I want the grid to have a fixed height of 100vh, despite the content of the template areas.
I tried to insert:

```
max-height : 100vh;
```

to the .grid-3x4 class but is not working.
I also tried to wrap the grid inside another class, setting the max-height on the containing class but no luck. How can I do this?

Comment: Well with `=` it's never gonna work on anything ...

Comment: @cbroe fixed, sorry

Comment: Did you figure this out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`max-height` (maximum height) sets a limit on the height of a container. You need to set a `min-height` (minimum height) to force a container to always have that minimum height.

A simple way to do is just to set that every cell within has a minimum and maximum height of 100vh (I did the example with 10vh so you could see without scrolling):

```css
.grid-3x4 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    'a b c '
    'd e f'
    'g h i'
    'l m n';
}

.grid-3x4 > div {
  min-height: 10vh;
  max-height: 10vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-3x4">
  <div>Aasdfasasdfsadfsadfsadf asdfasddfsadf sadfsadfasdfasdf sadfsadfasdfasdf sadfsadfasdfasdf sadfsadfasdfasdf</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</div>
```

(also https://jsfiddle.net/ppvo9y32/2/)

You should also set an `overflow` (for example, `overflow: hidden`) to control what happens when the content goes out of the boundaries of the cell.

Comment: This is not doing what I'm asking unfortunately. When you insert a bigger text than a single letter the sections of the grid keeps expanding over the minimum height.

Comment: So if I want a 100vh height and I have 4 fr, every fr must have a min-height and max-height of 25vh. It's working now, gonna try it extensively on my project.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the problem by limiting the overflow, which "forces" the grid to stay in its boundaries. So something like this:

```
.grid-3x4 {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-3x4 > div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).