# How to force CSS grid to be specific height

Tags: css, overflow, css-grid

I have found this question: [How to set max height to a CSS grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46699452/how-to-set-max-height-to-a-css-grid), which talks about setting a specific height to the elements of a grid. I want to set a height to the grid itself, though, and have any elements overflowing to have a scroll bar (refer to the figure below).

[image: Wanted Result]

Even though I set a `max-height` to the container element, the large text (`.top`) still overflows and makes the container element's height larger than its `max-height`. And since I don't know the size of the `.bottom` element (its height is `auto`), I can't set a `max-height` to the `.top` element.

```css
.container {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  grid-template: 1fr auto / 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "top" "bottom";
  background: red;
}

.top {
  background: blue;
  grid-area: top;
}

.bottom {
  background: green;
  grid-area: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin scelerisque blandit ipsum vitae vehicula. Vestibulum id urna ac odio scelerisque venenatis. Mauris blandit vitae tortor ac auctor. Donec pharetra accumsan eleifend. Fusce porta ante at turpis venenatis, sed luctus mi efficitur. Nunc eget metus pellentesque ante lacinia facilisis. Aenean magna nisi, feugiat at ullamcorper a, tincidunt id augue. Curabitur ut nisl eu risus convallis luctus et vitae enim. Ut vitae purus sed enim tempus convallis. Vestibulum consequat scelerisque ornare.</p>
    <p>Sed at urna turpis. Aenean vehicula, nunc elementum vehicula rutrum, sem orci ornare mauris, auctor ultricies quam enim quis sem. Praesent accumsan volutpat mollis. Proin tempus rhoncus lacus. Cras gravida, mauris sed suscipit vulputate, odio elit sagittis urna, non suscipit odio sapien eget ex. Ut vulputate ante sit amet diam tempus, eget tempus dolor sodales. Etiam quis orci posuere, interdum diam quis, tincidunt urna. Vivamus lectus lectus, hendrerit in sapien quis, tempor sollicitudin sem. Proin quis sem lectus. Fusce quis molestie enim, quis dapibus lacus. Nulla fringilla metus a odio lacinia feugiat. Vivamus rutrum diam placerat tristique scelerisque. Integer a iaculis justo, a tempus lorem.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>Little Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

So how can a specific-height grid still be achieved and have any elements that are too large have a scrollbar?

Comment: Solved with Javascript

Comment: Confused, the image you have added in your question doesn't reflect the output of the answer you have marked as being the solution. Whilst it may not be copy and pasted code from the link you presented, there are more than 1 way to skin a cat so to speak.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The image shows what I want, the code shows what I have

Comment: I want to set a height to the grid itself, though, and have any elements overflowing to have a scroll bar (refer to the figure below). Is what you stated, The image or figure you presented was replicated unlike the answer you marked as correct

Comment: That was a quick mockup, but if you disregard any margins/padding, it is exactly as the accepted answer shows

Comment: Ok, no worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set display: grid on the container, and overflow: auto on the top:

```css
.container {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  grid-template: 1fr auto / 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "top" "bottom";
  background: red;
  display: grid; /* added */
}

.top {
  background: blue;
  grid-area: top;
  overflow: auto; /* added */
}

.bottom {
  background: green;
  grid-area: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin scelerisque blandit ipsum vitae vehicula. Vestibulum id urna ac odio scelerisque venenatis. Mauris blandit vitae tortor ac auctor. Donec pharetra accumsan eleifend. Fusce porta ante at turpis venenatis, sed luctus mi efficitur. Nunc eget metus pellentesque ante lacinia facilisis. Aenean magna nisi, feugiat at ullamcorper a, tincidunt id augue. Curabitur ut nisl eu risus convallis luctus et vitae enim. Ut vitae purus sed enim tempus convallis. Vestibulum consequat scelerisque ornare.</p>
    <p>Sed at urna turpis. Aenean vehicula, nunc elementum vehicula rutrum, sem orci ornare mauris, auctor ultricies quam enim quis sem. Praesent accumsan volutpat mollis. Proin tempus rhoncus lacus. Cras gravida, mauris sed suscipit vulputate, odio elit sagittis urna, non suscipit odio sapien eget ex. Ut vulputate ante sit amet diam tempus, eget tempus dolor sodales. Etiam quis orci posuere, interdum diam quis, tincidunt urna. Vivamus lectus lectus, hendrerit in sapien quis, tempor sollicitudin sem. Proin quis sem lectus. Fusce quis molestie enim, quis dapibus lacus. Nulla fringilla metus a odio lacinia feugiat. Vivamus rutrum diam placerat tristique scelerisque. Integer a iaculis justo, a tempus lorem.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>Little Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm, very interesting. I did forget those in my example, indeed, but in my real code it didn't work either

Comment: Difficult to tell what was the problem with your real code....  Maybe some typo ?

Comment: Yeah, I actually took a completely different approach now, so it doesn't matter :)